# Integral of two Bessel functions product times Gaussian

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, gaussian-integral

Does anyone have a clue about how to solve this integral? Will it have a closed form?

$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}J_n(ax)J_n(bx)dx$

I've been searching materials and papers for a while, and did find anything about it... People had this integral 
$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}J_n(ax)J_n(bx)dx$ 
solved instead of the above form.

Comment: Just a correction... the exponential of e in the integral has a minus sign in front. (corrected in the question...)

Comment: In book: `Table of Integrals, Series, and Products
Eighth Edition` 6.618 example 5 page 706.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk wouldn't it be (6.633.1) rather than (6.618.5) where the Bessel functions have identical variables $J_\mu(\beta x)J_\nu(\beta x)$?

Comment: I can only find the PDF of the seventh edition. Then, I think the equations you are talking about is 6.633 example 1, page 707 in the seventh edition. Thanks a lot for your help! (But sadly, the result has an infinite summation inside, which is still very hard to handle. :( )

Comment: @PaulEnta.`6.633.3` it fits more to OP question (First integral).